# Visual Studio: quick access to most used files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, add-in

The solution I work on is quite big so it can require a lot of clicks to get to the desired file. I spend 90% of the time working with 8-10 files from this solution so it would be really convenient to have some kind of "Favorites" in my solution so I could jump to the most used files quickly. "Recent files" doesn't cut it, so maybe you know some extensions for VS2010 that do that? Google didn't provide any good options so I decided to give it a shot here and ask what do you use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you want to see implemented? It's not at all clear from the question what features you wish were added to the interface. Why not open all 8-10 files at once, and switch between them using tabs? No add-ins required.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I want to be able to add a file from Solution Explorer to the list of "favorites" and I want the button/submenu/something with a list of these favorite files, so I can open them quickly when I want to.

Comment: There's no "list of favorites", so that doesn't help me much. This is *exactly* what's already provided in the form of the "Recent Files" menu, but you say that doesn't work for you. Why not, and how is your proposed solution different?

Comment: @Cody Gray: "Recent Files" is filled with anything that was opened recently. I want to make a list myself so it stays the same regardless of how often I use files in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite what you asked for, but it'll help endlessly:

In vanilla VS2010, hit `Ctrl-Comma` (by default) for the "Navigate To" window.  You can type a partial file, class or method name and it'll show you a list of where that appears in your solution, and you can open directly from there.

The DevExpress plugins also have a "Recently Used File" window (Ctrl-Shift-Period by default, I think) that does similar, but only shows files you've recently used (not classes or methods).  I have to say, though, I've not used that since I've had VS2010.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful and it does help, I mark it as answer since there are no better options.

Answer (score 1):

Wow! A question since 2011 that is still valid to date.

1. From View Menu click Bookmark Window
2. open your favorite file
3. click any line - preferably the beginning of the file
4. from the Bookmarks Window, click the icon "Toggle a bookmark on the current line."

Very convenient!

Comment: works perfect.  and i docked it to the left of VS so it's an easy pop out now to all my frequent files.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this particular feature of the PowerTools myself, but it could do the trick:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/08/03/quick-access-extension.aspx

Comment: That doesn't look like it does what I need and if it does, it's a giant overkill, but thank you. I'm trying to avoid installing PowerTools anyway